# ScatterGeo vs ScatterMapbox in Plotly.JS (Performance vs. coloring options)

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly, mapbox, plotly.js

I have a little conundrum I was hoping someone could shed a bit of light on.

Basically I have a bunch of paired coordinates (roughly 3000), i.e. two points that needs to be connected with a line. Depending on some value, this line (plus the two data points) needs to have a certain color. In my situation, I need to plot maybe 2-300 of those pairs with different color, and some kind of text attached to it, where the rest can have the same color, width, etc.

In Plotly JS you can give a whole list of coordinates, separated by a None for each pair, and then it draws a line between each pair. For example:

```
lon = [50.2, 51.2, None, 51.8, 49.6, None, 53.1, 53.6]
lat = [10.2, 11.2, None, 12.8, 13.6, None, 12.1, 11.6]
```

The problem is that it seems like I can't change the color of the line for each individual pair. I can do it for the markers by just adding:

```
color = ["red", "red", None, "blue", blue", None, "purple", "purple"]
```

But lines, I haven't been able to find anything that helps me. Again, this is not an issue for the remaining pairs (2800 pairs left). They can be all the same color. However, the 200 that needs different colors and stuff, well, you can't (at least not to my knowledge).

In order to fix this, well, I can do it as `traces` instead. So for each coordinate pair that needs coloring, I can just create a `trace` with a line color, marker color, etc. The problem there is, that when I reach something like a few hundred, `scattermapbox` gets really poor performance.

I can then try to use `scattergeo` instead, which is more tolerant towards `traces` (in my experience). However, `scattergeos` problem seems to be that if I then plot the remaining 2800 pairs, even with one list like for `scattermapbox` (so not 2800 new traces) then IT gets really low performance. So I'm kind of stuck between this annoying middle where none of the options can fully complete my task without it missing some key feature such as performance or coloring.

Am I just missing something, or is that just how it is ?